# Sprite sumindo no meu jogo (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame, game

Estou fazendo um jogo onde se tem 2 personagens e o objetivo deles são destruir os lixos e derrotar o boss

nele eu estava fazendo a função de colisão do boss que ao ser atingido pelas balas dos personagens ele tomasse dano feito isso ao rodar meu codigo percebi que as balas estavam invisiveis porém até certo ponto e andando um pouco pra frente com o personagem as balas começam a aparecer porém elas não atigem o boss

Aqui meu codigo:

```
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
import random

pygame.init()

# Definições
FPS = 60
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
largura, altura = 980, 560
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((largura, altura))
pygame.display.set_caption("Jogos Digitais")
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

# Classes
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_path, vida_inicial=100):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.image.load(image_path).convert()
        self.surf.set_colorkey((234, 0, 255), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
        self.vida = vida_inicial
        self.vida_maxima = vida_inicial
        self.cooldown = 30  # Cooldown em frames
        self.cooldown_timer = 0

    def perder_vida(self, quantidade):
        self.vida = max(0, self.vida - quantidade)

    def resetar_vida(self):
        self.vida = self.vida_maxima
        
    def atirar(self):
        if self.cooldown_timer <= 0:
            self.cooldown_timer = self.cooldown
            return True
        return False

    def atualizar_cooldown(self):
        if self.cooldown_timer > 0:
            self.cooldown_timer -= 1

class Boss(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_path, vida_inicial=200):
        super(Boss, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.image.load(image_path).convert()
        self.surf.set_colorkey((234, 0, 255), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
        self.vida = vida_inicial
        self.vida_maxima = vida_inicial 

    def perder_vida(self, quantidade):
        self.vida = max(0, self.vida - quantidade)

    def resetar_vida(self):
        self.vida = self.vida_maxima

    def desenhar_barra_vida(self, screen):
        largura_barra = int((self.vida / self.vida_maxima) * 120)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (largura - 130, altura // 15 - 30, largura_barra, 20))

class Lixo(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Lixo, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.image.load('lixo.png').convert()
        self.surf.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
            center=(
                random.randint(largura + 20, largura + 100),
                random.randint(0, altura),
            )
        )
        self.speed = random.randint(5, 20)
        
    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()

class Bala(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_path, speed, damage):
        super(Bala, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.image.load(image_path).convert()
        self.surf.set_colorkey((234, 0, 255), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
        self.speed = speed
        self.damage = damage

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speed
        if self.rect.right < 0 or self.rect.left > largura or self.rect.y < 0 or self.rect.y > altura:
            self.kill()

# Inicialização
p1x, p1y = 0, 0
p2x, p2y = 0, 100
vida_p1, vida_p2 = 100, 100

ADDLIXO = pygame.USEREVENT + 3
pygame.time.set_timer(ADDLIXO, 800)

lixos = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

balas_planta = pygame.sprite.Group()
balas_agua = pygame.sprite.Group()

player1 = Player('personagem1.png')
player2 = Player('personagem2.png')
all_sprites.add(player1, player2)

boss = Boss('boss.png')
all_sprites.add(boss)

# Loop principal
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (0, altura // 3, largura, 1))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (0, 2 * altura // 3, largura, 1))

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, largura, int(altura * 0.15)))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), (0, int(altura * 0.15), largura, int(altura * 0.50)))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (0, int(altura * 0.575), largura, int(altura * 0.50)))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == ADDLIXO:
            new_lixo = Lixo()
            lixos.add(new_lixo)
            all_sprites.add(new_lixo)
            
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[K_UP] and p1y > int(altura * 0.05):
        p1y -= 5
    if keys[K_DOWN] and p1y < int(altura * 0.74) - player1.surf.get_height():
        p1y += 5
    if keys[K_LEFT] and p1x > 0:
        p1x -= 5
    if keys[K_RIGHT] and p1x < largura - player1.surf.get_width():
        p1x += 5
    if keys[K_RETURN]:
        if player1.atirar():
            nova_bala = Bala('bala_agua.png', 10, 10)
            nova_bala.rect.midtop = player1.rect.midtop
            balas_agua.add(nova_bala)
            all_sprites.add(nova_bala)

    if keys[K_w] and p2y > int(altura * 0.05):
        p2y -= 5
    if keys[K_s] and p2y < int(altura * 0.74) - player2.surf.get_height():
        p2y += 5
    if keys[K_a] and p2x > 0:
        p2x -= 5
    if keys[K_d] and p2x < largura - player2.surf.get_width():
        p2x += 5
    if keys[K_SPACE]:
        if player2.atirar():
            nova_bala = Bala('bala_planta.png', 10, 10)
            nova_bala.rect.midtop = player2.rect.midtop
            balas_planta.add(nova_bala)
            all_sprites.add(nova_bala)

    player1.atualizar_cooldown()
    player2.atualizar_cooldown()
    
    lixos.update()
    balas_agua.update()
    balas_planta.update()
    all_sprites.update()

    player1.rect.topleft = (p1x, p1y)  # Atualize a posição do retângulo de colisão do jogador 1
    player2.rect.topleft = (p2x, p2y)  # Atualize a posição do retângulo de colisão do jogador 2

    for bala in balas_agua.sprites() + balas_planta.sprites():
        if bala.rect.colliderect(boss.rect):
            boss.perder_vida(bala.damage)
            bala.kill()
        else:
            for lixo in lixos.sprites():
                if bala.rect.colliderect(lixo.rect):
                    bala.kill()
                    lixo.kill()

    for lixo in lixos.sprites():
        screen.blit(lixo.surf, lixo.rect)

        # Colisão do lixo com os personagens
        if player1.rect.colliderect(lixo.rect) and player1.vida > 0:
            player1.perder_vida(10)
            lixo.rect.topleft = (largura + 20, random.randint(0, altura))
        if player2.rect.colliderect(lixo.rect) and player2.vida > 0:
            player2.perder_vida(10)
            lixo.rect.topleft = (largura + 20, random.randint(0, altura))

    for bala in balas_agua.sprites() + balas_planta.sprites():
        screen.blit(bala.surf, bala.rect)

    screen.blit(player1.surf, (p1x, p1y))
    screen.blit(player2.surf, (p2x, p2y))

    screen.blit(boss.surf, (largura - 190, altura // 13))

    boss.desenhar_barra_vida(screen)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (10, altura - 30, (vida_p1 / player1.vida_maxima) * 100, 20))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), (largura - (vida_p2 / player2.vida_maxima) * 100 - 10, altura - 30, (vida_p2 / player2.vida_maxima) * 100, 20))

    # Verifica se a vida chegou a zero e mata o personagem
    if player1.vida <= 0:
        player1.resetar_vida()
    if player2.vida <= 0:
        player2.resetar_vida()

    for lixo in lixos.sprites():
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(lixo, balas_planta, True):
            lixo.kill()
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(lixo, balas_agua, True):
            lixo.kill()   

    # Remove os sprites marcados para remoção
    balas_agua.remove()
    balas_planta.remove()
    lixos.remove()

    boss.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que eu percebi, testando seu jogo, no canto superior esquerdo as balas estão colidindo com o boss, ao printar nesse trecho, só por curiosidade:

```
for bala in balas_agua.sprites() + balas_planta.sprites():
        if bala.rect.colliderect(boss.rect):
            print(boss.rect)
```

temos o seguinte resultado:

```
<rect(0, 0, altura, largura)>
```

(substitui os valores de altura e largura da imagem que usei provisoriamente, só pra não confundir, já que a rect vem da imagem)

o que significa que a rect do seu boss está na posição 0,0 mesmo que a imagem esteja sendo blitada em outro canto.

Eu costumo definir a posição das imagens no init da propria class, utilizando o sprite.Group.draw() para desenhar os sprites.

Acho que você pode começar por ai para resolver seu problema, já que você está blitando a imagem do boss aonde você quer, mas a rect está na posição 0,0 , independente do valor que você coloque pro boss pra blitar.

um exemplo pra class do Boss seria:

```
class Boss(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_path, vida_inicial=200, x, y):
        super(Boss, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_path).convert()
        self.surf.set_colorkey((234, 0, 255), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.vida = vida_inicial
        self.vida_maxima = vida_inicial 

    def perder_vida(self, quantidade):
        self.vida = max(0, self.vida - quantidade)

    def resetar_vida(self):
        self.vida = self.vida_maxima

    def desenhar_barra_vida(self, screen):
        largura_barra = int((self.vida / self.vida_maxima) * 120)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (largura - 130, altura // 15 - 30, largura_barra, 20))
```

cria a class com

```
boss = Boss('boss.png',largura - 190, altura // 13)
all_sprites.add(boss)
```

e ai você coloca no loop do jogo:

```
all_sprites.draw()
```

ao invés de blitar cada um dos sprites (já que esse all_sprites contém todos os sprites do seu jogo, você facilita fazendo o .draw() de tudo.)

Espero que isso ajude.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).